# How can I extract a wrapped C++ type from a Python type using boost::python?

Tags: c++, boost-python, py++

I've wrapped a C++ class using Py++ and everything is working great in Python. I can instantiate the c++ class, call methods, etc.

I'm now trying to embed some Python into a C++ application. This is also working fine for the most-part. I can call functions on a Python module, get return values, etc.

The python code I'm calling returns one of the classes that I wrapped:

```
import _myextension as myext
def run_script(arg):
    my_cpp_class = myext.MyClass()
    return my_cpp_class
```

I'm calling this function from C++ like this:

```
// ... excluding error checking, ref counting, etc. for brevity ...
PyObject *pModule, *pFunc, *pArgs, *pReturnValue;

Py_Initialize();
pModule = PyImport_Import(PyString_FromString("cpp_interface"));
pFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, "run_script");
pArgs = PyTuple_New(1); PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, 0, PyString_FromString("an arg"));


pReturnValue = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pArgs);

bp::extract< MyClass& > extractor(pReturnValue); // PROBLEM IS HERE
if (extractor.check()) {                         // This check is always false
    MyClass& cls = extractor();
}
```

The problem is the extractor never actually extracts/converts the PyObject* to MyClass (i.e. extractor.check() is always false).

According to [the docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/python/doc/tutorial/doc/html/python/object.html#python.extracting_c___objects) this is the correct way to extract a wrapped C++ class.

I've tried returning basic data types (ints/floats/dicts) from the Python function and all of them are extracted properly.

Is there something I'm missing? Is there another way to get the data and cast to MyClass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the error. I wasn't linking my bindings in my main executable because the bindings were compiled in a separate project that created the python extension only.

I assumed that by loading the extension using `pModule = PyImport_Import(PyString_FromString("cpp_interface"));` the bindings would be loaded as well, but this is not the case.

**To fix the problem, I simply added the files that contain my boost::python bindings (for me, just wrapper.cpp) to my main project and re-built.**